# WP nonce verification

Tags: plugins, coding-standards

I'm busy testing out the plugin through Travis and the only issues remaining are:

**Processing form data without nonce verification**

It seems to be relating to this action:

```php
/**
 * An action that handles the call from PayFast to tell Give the order was Completed
 */

function payfast_ipn() {
    $give_options = give_get_settings();

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['m_payment_id'] ) ) {

        if ( give_is_test_mode() ) {
            $pf_host = 'https://sandbox.payfast.co.za/eng/query/validate';
            give_insert_payment_note( $_REQUEST['m_payment_id'], 'ITN callback has been triggered.' );
        } else {
            $pf_host = 'https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/query/validate';
        }

        $pf_error         = false;
        $pf_param_string  = '';
        $validate_string  = '';

        if ( ! $pf_error ) {
            // Strip any slashes in data.
            foreach wp_verify_nonce( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
                $_POST[ $key ] = stripslashes( $val );
            }
            foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
                if ( 'signature' != $key ) {
                    $pf_param_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode( $val ) . '&';
                }
            }
            $pf_param_string = substr( $pf_param_string, 0, - 1 );
            $validate_string = $pf_param_string;
            if ( isset( $give_options['payfast_pass_phrase'] ) ) {
                $pass_phrase = trim( $give_options['payfast_pass_phrase'] );
                if ( ! empty( $pass_phrase ) ) {
                    $pf_param_string .= '&pass_phrase=' . urlencode( $pass_phrase );
                }
            }
        }
        $signature = md5( $pf_param_string );

        if ( give_is_test_mode() ) {
            // translators:
            give_insert_payment_note( $_REQUEST['m_payment_id'], sprintf( __( 'Signature Returned %1$s. Generated Signature %2$s.', 'payfast_give' ), $_POST['signature'], $signature ) );
        }

        if ( $signature != $_POST['signature'] ) {
            $pf_error = 'SIGNATURE';
            $error   = array(
                'oursig' => $signature,
                'vars'   => $_POST,
            );
        }

        if ( ! $pf_error ) {
            $valid_hosts = array(
                'www.payfast.co.za',
                'sandbox.payfast.co.za',
                'w1w.payfast.co.za',
                'w2w.payfast.co.za',
            );

            $valid_ips  = array();
            $sender_ip = payfast_get_realip();
            foreach ( $valid_hosts as $pf_hostname ) {
                $ips = gethostbynamel( $pf_hostname );

                if ( false !== $ips ) {
                    $valid_ips = array_merge( $valid_ips, $ips );
                }
            }

            $valid_ips = array_unique( $valid_ips );

            if ( ! in_array( $sender_ip, $valid_ips ) ) {
                $pf_error = array(
                    'FROM'  => $sender_ip,
                    'VALID' => $valid_ips,
                );
            }
        }

        /*
        * If it fails for any reason, add that to the order.
        */
        if ( false !== $pf_error ) {
            // translators:
            give_insert_payment_note( $_POST['m_payment_id'], sprintf( __( 'Payment Failed. The error is %s.', 'payfast_give' ), print_r( $pf_error, true ) ) );
        } else {

            $response = wp_remote_post(
                $pf_host, array(
                    'method'      => 'POST',
                    'timeout'     => 60,
                    'redirection' => 5,
                    'httpversion' => '1.0',
                    'blocking'    => true,
                    'headers'     => array(),
                    'body'        => $validate_string,
                    'cookies'     => array(),
                )
            );

            if ( give_is_test_mode() ) {
                give_insert_payment_note(
                    $_POST['m_payment_id'], sprintf(
                        // translators:
                        __( 'PayFast ITN Params - %1$s %2$s.', 'payfast_give' ), $pf_host, print_r(
                            array(
                                'method'      => 'POST',
                                'timeout'     => 60,
                                'redirection' => 5,
                                'httpversion' => '1.0',
                                'blocking'    => true,
                                'headers'     => array(),
                                'body'        => $validate_string,
                                'cookies'     => array(),
                            ), true
                        )
                    )
                );
                // translators:
                give_insert_payment_note( $_POST['m_payment_id'], sprintf( __( 'PayFast ITN Response. %s.', 'payfast_give' ), print_r( $response['body'], true ) ) );
            }

            if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) && ( $response['response']['code'] >= 200 || $response['response']['code'] < 300 ) ) {
                $res = $response['body'];
                if ( false == $res ) {
                    $pf_error = $response;

                }
            }
        }

        if ( ! $pf_error ) {
            $lines = explode( "\n", $res );
        }

        if ( ! $pf_error ) {
            $result = trim( $lines[0] );

            if ( strcmp( $result, 'VALID' ) === 0 ) {
                if ( 'COMPLETE' == $_POST['payment_status'] ) {

                    if ( ! empty( $_POST['custom_str2'] ) ) {
                        $subscription = new Give_Subscription( $_POST['custom_str2'], true );
                        // Retrieve pending subscription from database and update it's status to active and set proper profile ID.
                        $subscription->update(
                            array(
                                'profile_id' => $_POST['token'],
                                'status'     => 'active',
                            )
                        );
                    }
                    give_set_payment_transaction_id( $_POST['m_payment_id'], $_POST['pf_payment_id'] );
                    // translators:
                    give_insert_payment_note( $_POST['m_payment_id'], sprintf( __( 'PayFast Payment Completed. The Transaction Id is %s.', 'payfast_give' ), $_POST['pf_payment_id'] ) );
                    give_update_payment_status( $_POST['m_payment_id'], 'publish' );

                } else {
                    // translators:
                    give_insert_payment_note( $_POST['m_payment_id'], sprintf( __( 'PayFast Payment Failed. The Response is %s.', 'payfast_give' ), print_r( $response['body'], true ) ) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'payfast_ipn' );
```

How would I go about to add the WP Nonce? Finding it tricky to apply.

Comment: You're using `$_POST`, is this coming from a form? If so, you can add [`wp_nonce_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/) to that and check the nonce's validity before this code happens

Comment: Coming from a request call I've extended the code to show the whole action.

Answer (score 0):

If this is coming from a form you can use this code to add the nonce to it:

```
// Create an nonce, and add it as a query var in a link to perform an action.
$nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'my-nonce' );

<form action='youraction?_wpnonce=<?php echo $nonce?>'>
    <!-- Form Contents -->
</form>
```

Then you can add this to where you are processing the form:

```
$nonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];

if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my-nonce' ) ) {

     die( 'Security check' ); 

} else {

     // Do stuff here.
}
```